# Laravel Export From View

Tags: laravel, export

I added an export button to a blade view however im getting the following error..

**Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TripController::export(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected**

This is the HTML table i want to be exported to a excel document
[image]

**TripsExport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Trip;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;

class TripsExport implements FromView
{
    public function view(): View
    {
      return view('trips.edit', [
          'events' => Events::all()
      ]);
    }
}
```

**trip.edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row welcome text-center">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="display-6"> {{ $trip->destination }} Itinerary </h1>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row welcome text-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h4 class="display-8"> {{$trip->startdate}} - {{$trip->enddate}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-12">

  <a href="/trips" class="btn btn-secondary">Go back</a>
  <a href="/trips/{{$trip->id}}/edit/AddEvent" class="btn btn-success"> Add to Itinerary</a>
  <a href="{{route('export')}}" class="btn btn-secondary">Export</a>
</div>
</div>

<br/>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead class="thead">
            <tr class="warning">
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Event Name</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($trip->events as $event)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $event->categories->category }}</td>
                <td>{{ $event->event_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $event->start_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ $event->end_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ $event->time }} </td>
                <td>{{ $event->address }} </td>
                <td>{{ $event->notes }} </td>
                <th>
                <a href="/events/{{$event->id}}/editEventForm" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Edit</a>
              </th>
            <th>
            <form action="{{route('events.destroy',[$event->id])}}" method="POST">
              @method('DELETE')
              @csrf
              <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </form>
          </th>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <br />
    <hr>


    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading"></div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <br>
        {!! $calendar_details->calendar() !!}
        {!! $calendar_details->script() !!}
      </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

**TripController.php**

```
public function export($type)
    {
      return Excel::download(new TripsExport, 'itinerary.' . $type);
    }
```

**Routes**

```
//Exporting
Route::get('export', 'TripController@export')->name('export');
Route::get('importExportView', 'TripController@importExportView');
Route::post('import', 'TripController@import')->name('import');
```

Comment: Please share your routes...

Comment: sorry routes added now

Comment: You might have to create a route with Route parameter E.g. Route::get('export/{type}', 'TripController@export`

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your routes :

```
Route::get('export/{type?}', 'TripController@export')->name('export');
```

and then in your controller :

```
public function export($type = 'xls')
    {
      return Excel::download(new TripsExport, 'itinerary.' . $type);
    }
```

then in your blade, you can even use this :

```
{{route('export')}}
```

or this :

```
{{route('export', 'xlsx')}}
```

If you want to export a single Trip **instead** :

```
Route::get('/{trip}/export/{type?}', 'TripController@export')->name('export');
```

```
public function export(Trip $trip, $type = 'xls')
    {
      return Excel::download(new TripsExport($trip), 'itinerary.' . $type);
    }
```

```
class TripsExport implements FromView
{

    public $trip;

    public function __construct(Trip $trip){
         $this->trip = $trip;
    }

    public function view(): View
    {
       // eager load everything you need
       $this->trip->load('events.category');

      return view('trips.edit', [
          'trip' => $this->trip
      ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error undefined variable 'trip' now.. do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: something is missing either in your controller or in your view, you are passing eventS to the view, but the view expect a trip to get $trip->events, I will edit my answer if you want to export a single trip

Answer (score 1):

In your route file, you have export route without any parameter, if you want the type to be dynamic then you will have to create a route with a route parameter like this one:

```
Route::get('export/{type}', 'TripController@export');
```

Or you can set a default value for the type parameter in the export function

```
public function export($type = 'excel') // this is just an example type
{
  return Excel::download(new TripsExport, 'itinerary.' . $type);
}
```

This should fix your problem

Best.

Comment: I added the default type getting the error "No ReaderType or WriterType could be detected. Make sure you either pass a valid extension to the filename or pass an explicit type."

Comment: Will you please update the code in your question then I will be able to understand better @Laura